# Just a value is valid for JSON

Tags: json

I want to know if the next value is valid as a JSON format

```
1223452234
```

I am using AFNetworking in my iOS app and allow the parse of it with

```
readingOptions: .AllowFragments
```

And it works... but it is a valid JSON? what's the name of that kind of things?

Thanks

Comment: Some parsers only allow the root element to be an object or an array, while others accept any type. The latter group would gladly parse that as a number. The latest JSON specification mentions both behaviours ([RFC 7159 §2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-2)).

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you must be in an array or object type for the root element.

This means you could have something like this if you really wanted it to be as "small and simple" as possible.

```
[ 
     12341234 
]
```

or this if you need keys.

```
{
    "test": 321321312
}
```

I don't think the numbers by themselves are valid and they're definitely not standard.